# Is it possible to virtualize Windows 7 on an 7th Gen. Intel CPU (Kaby Lake)?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

by now it's well known that Windows 7 isn't supported bare-metal on Kaby Lake CPUs.

Is it possible to run a virtualized Windows 7 on an Kaby Lake host (preferably running Linux)?

Comment: @Ramhound _It is possible to run Windows 7 on Kaby Lake hardware Microsoft backtracked on that._ Do you have any source on that?

Comment: Was confused between Skylake and KabyLake: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4012982/the-processor-is-not-supported-together-with-the-windows-version-that- but a patch exist for that problem and there is actually an existing answer here for that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to run a virtualized Windows 7 on an Kaby Lake host (preferably running Linux)?

Yes, it is possible. https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/i-just-realized-windows-7-cannot-be-installed-on-a-kaby-lake.2505972/:

> The virtual environment is running off a generic Intel CPU created by the virtualization software.